# Overlaying images over camera. Augmented reality

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality

So, I'm trying to create a Augmented reality app on android (client/server).
My question is if i can overlay images and text boxes over the camera in real time or only if i have the capture to display it on the screen and add the extra information

If the first version can be implemented can someone help me with  some starting code or links with suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar for one of my apps,
And the way i did it is by placing an empty View on top of camera surfaceView using FrameLayout, then used onDraw method in the View class, to play with canvas and put anything i wanted on top of the camera view, you can practically do everything with Canvas, and since literally your view is overlaying the camera surfaceView, will do exactly the trick you are trying to accomplish here...

Regards!